# How I can change the color of the text of Ant Design TabPane?

Tags: reactjs, antd

I use a Tabs with some TabPane in my code but the text stay always in Blue, I want to change it to grey. 
I try several things but none fuction.

I try:

this for apply the text color with the parent:

```
<Tabs style={{ height: "fit-content",font: "#363636" }}  >
```

and

```
<Tabs style={{ height: "fit-content",color: "#363636" }}  >
```

this for each the children :

```
<TabPane tab={t("tabPanelGeneral/name")} key="1" style={{ color: "#363636" }}>
```

and

```
<TabPane tab={t("tabPanelGeneral/name")} key="1" style={{ font: "#363636" }}>
```

Comment: can you explain more what actually you need ?

Answer (score 12):

Putting it here if someone still needs it
You can use `tabBarStyle` prop to add custom css. [source](https://2x.ant.design/components/tabs/)

To change the color of the active tab, You need to update `color` of the button:

```
.ant-tabs-tab.ant-tabs-tab-active .ant-tabs-tab-btn {
   color: #363636 !important; 
   font-weight: 500;
}
```

To change the color of the blue bottom bar:

```
.ant-tabs-ink-bar {
   position: absolute;
   background: #000000;
   pointer-events: none;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! good solution. The "!important" part though is not necessary. it works for me without it.

Answer (score 5):

if you change the color of the tab text then put CSS like this

demo [codesandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/nervous-tereshkova-bj5xz) you view demo

```
.ant-tabs-tab {
  color: #363636 !important;
}

.ant-tabs-tab-active {
  color: #363636 !important;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can set

```
.ant-tabs-ink-bar {
   background: none;
}
```

And use a custom-tab

```
.custom-tab{
   height : fit-content;
   color:#363636;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can apply css for your active tab.

```
.ant-tabs-nav .ant-tabs-tab-active {
   color: '#363636';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@osama's answers works good but I wanted to change the bottom bar color also where his answer was not working.

Below code is working if you want to change the border color:

```
.ant-tabs-ink-bar {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ae9572;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

you simply can add classNames to your components and add their styles on your style sheet :

```js
<Tabs className="custom-tab"  >
```

and the style sheet :

```css
.custom-tab{
   height : fit-content;
   color:#363636;
}
```

Comment: This is the main class you are showing. Unfortunately this is not the answer to the question